# Geocoding in 64 bits with background geoprocessing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, geocoding, 64bit

I have 10.1 SP1 installed plus the background geoprocessing patch for 64 bit geoprocessing.
Im trying to geocode a large file, so wanted to take advantage of 64 bits processing. My Surprise when i try to change properties of  locators  to make use of runtime memory limits to more the 2024 it gives me an error saying out of range limits. How can i process set up locators as described in [this blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/02/09/tuning-a-locator-for-improved-performance/)

I also have enabled the background geoprocessing in ArcCatalog > Geoprocessing options and created a model to run the job, but when looking at taskmanager at run time its always a process of arccatalog (32bits) running and nothing related to 64 bits.

Comment: Did you uncheck the box on the model properties (general page) of "always run in foreground"? If you haven't unchecked that, the model will not run in the background.

Comment: Just did that now, but it still shows in task mngr as an ArcCatalog application (32 bits), nothing points to a 64 bit process. thanks

Comment: Are you sure? You should be looking for a RuntimeLocalServer.exe process. There will be 2, one will be bigger than the other. This is the 64bit BG process running your tool. [in addition to the check you have no dialog locking out ArcCatalog as this disappears when running in BG]

Comment: I can see both RuntimelocalServer.exe processes, but they seem to be stall, no memory activity neither cpu, would expect to see memory going up but that's not the case. Is this the expected behavior ? And still not finding the way to increase the RuntimeMemory above 2024mb on locators properties.

Comment: My mistake was running with model open , now i closed the model and i can see activity in one of the RunTimeLocalServer.exe processes going up. --still not finding the way to increase the RuntimeMemory above 2024mb on locators properties. Thanks